# How can I unlock a HTG locker folder?

Tags: windows

I created a HTG locker folder with password a few months ago (I just looked it up on Google and found out how to create one).

Now when I try to open the locker, the dialogue box appears where I have to punch in the password, but it does not let me enter.

The dialogue box keeps blinking and all of my important docs and lot of pictures are stored in that folder. Now how would one unlock the locked folder?

Comment: Hmm....I'm not sure your question is appropriate to this group as how do I know that you are not simply trying to hack the locker folder of another users?  I'm not sure descriptions to bypass password security is allowed here.

Comment: Are you talking about this? http://www.howtogeek.com/105633/how-to-create-a-password-protected-folder-without-any-extra-software/

Comment: @mdpc: lstn the folder is mine and i knw the password too..but the window where i have to punch in the password blinks and goes by the time i try to type half of the password..i dnt knw whether the question is appropriate or not..i tried findin out searchin in google..no help..so thought will check out goin this website..am not a coder or computer expert..just a normal user!!

Comment: @slhck: thank u..yep it is the same steps usin which i created the folder..am aware of the password..it used to get unlocked initially..after few months the problem i mentioned above started happening..

Comment: This script/bat rears its head once again.  Its completely useless and easily bypassed.  Use real encryption if you want security/pricacy.

Comment: @anu: I never saw your answer confirming that you were able to access your files successfully using the steps I provided (@name notifies people only in comments, not in answers). Apologies for not responding sooner; you're most welcome and your effusive thanks is appreciation enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Explorer's **Folder Options** dialog (see instructions for [XP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/folderopt_overview.mspx) and [Vista+](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/295-folder-options-open.html)), along with ensuring **Show hidden files, folders, and drives** is selected, you need to ensure the **Hide protected operating system files** option is *not* selected:

[image: 3]

This should show you all the folders/files marked with +H (hidden) and +S (system) attributes.

Now simply look for a folder named **HTG Locker**. This is the so-called **Private** folder you placed all your files in, and you can directly open it in Explorer without any password.

Answer (score 0):

if you learned this trick by googling "how to password protect folders". Then we probably did the same thing.

You would have a batch file right? (locker.bat),

step one: right click it, then "edit".
step two: notepad will open, you will have to find the text im giving you below.

```
:UNLOCK  
echo Enter password to unlock folder  
set/p "pass=>"  
if NOT %pass%== "*PASSWORD GOES HERE*" goto FAIL  
attrib -h -s "HTG Locker"
```

step three: Change the string "PASSWOR GOES HERE" to your password. Change it to something easy like, apples.

step 4: once done, save as *filename*.**bat**.

step 5: click the new batch file

Comment: That so-called password does nothing, and the batch file is useless. You don't even need it to access the hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but i've found a simple answer to this. It seems this kind of folder is *not safe* at all. All you have to do is access it from **android**, it won't ask you for a password and it will grant you full access.
To do this, share the folder to the network, download ES File Explorer, and access it from LAN. Or just copy the folder to your android device. You're done.