# How do i hide Windows batch file or hide the password in this text?

Tags: command-line, passwords, batch-file

I have a code that I save into a text file and label it locker.bat, and it will hide a folder for me. But the problem is I can just right click and click edit and find the password (like down below the password is password_goes_here). This is Windows 8 by the way.

How do I hide the password so people can't see it,or can I make it to where they can't edit it?

```
cls 
@ECHO OFF 
title Folder Private 
if EXIST "HTG Locker" goto UNLOCK 
if NOT EXIST Private goto MDLOCKER 
:CONFIRM 
echo Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N) 
set/p "cho=>" 
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==n goto END 
if %cho%==N goto END 
echo Invalid choice. 
goto CONFIRM 
:LOCK 
ren Private "HTG Locker" 
attrib +h +s "HTG Locker" 
echo Folder locked 
goto End 
:UNLOCK 
echo Enter password to unlock folder 
set/p "pass=>" 
if NOT %pass%== PASSWORD_GOES_HERE goto FAIL 
attrib -h -s "HTG Locker" 
ren "HTG Locker" Private 
echo Folder Unlocked successfully 
goto End 
:FAIL 
echo Invalid password 
goto end 
:MDLOCKER 
md Private 
echo Private created successfully 
goto End 
:End
```

Comment: Why even bother?  Anybody who has access to your files can find your hidden directory and unhide it (or even access it *without* unhiding it) anyway; the password has no value.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Use a proper programming language that allows you to compile the code, and employ encryption/obfuscation techniques so the password is not easily visible to any inquisitive person.

Option 2: There are Batch to EXE converters you can use. A tech-savvy user can probably use a hex editor (or even a text editor or a *strings* utility) to view the plain text password string inside the executable, but your average user will be stumped.

P.S. HTG Locker is near useless anyway. All it [does](https://superuser.com/a/573264/138343) is set the +S and +H attributes for the folder.

Comment: it is a work pc i cant "tamper" with folder options. i don't have the administration paswword.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. If you don't have the permissions to set the +SH attribs for a folder then neither can the utility, unless you elevate. In fact, using the utility on a work PC might well be a contravention of IT policy, and doing it manually would be better than using an unapproved third-party program.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it's at the cost of you being able to edit the program after.

What you need to do is grab this utility [here](https://bat2exe.codeplex.com/). All it is is a Batch file to EXE compiler, i.e. hides the password, but you're not going to be able to edit it after compilation.

As pointed out by @EBGreen, you would still only need a Hex editor to view the password.

However, there is one product I used to use, but it's payware. You can find it below, and it uses encryption and a decoder module it compiles into the EXE. This would be the only real option to fully mask the password, as it encrypts the batch file before converting it.

http://www.battoexeconverter.com/

Comment: this is what i want

Comment: if it's what you want, then mark this as the answer, and use the program to compile the batch to an EXE

Comment: well im not one to download something that has only been up for 7 days and i meant that it would be prefered if i cant edit the file. that would sovle the problem

Comment: how exactly has it only been up for 7 days? the time stamp is: `Jan 12, 2013 at 11:16 AM`

Comment: the information in the batch file is right there in the exe if you use the linked utility fyi.

Comment: so it would be with pretty much every bat2exe compiler

Comment: My point is that it doesn't really hide the password at all as you state. It just means you need to use a hex editor to open the file rather than notepad.

Comment: It would still be enough to fool average joe

Comment: Better now @EBGreen?

Comment: I had already pointed out the problem with compiling and the usage of a hex editor in my answer itself. As for that program you mentioned, it's a joke. No matter what so-called encryption it employs, naturally to run the batch file it has to be decrypted first. Look in the Temp folder and there it is. So obvious. These techniques are all security theatre BS, but still people fall for them and even pay for such programs. Anyone with half a brain would use true encryption of the actual files/folders.

Comment: I gotta agree there, now time for bed...